# python wrapper to execute two commands

Tags: python

I am trying to run two commands using python on a remote server. Although the 
function main() executes, only the first command is executed, the second does not. Can somebody help me on this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import shlex, subprocess

sut = sys.argv[1]
pp = sys.argv[2]
sut_adapter = sys.argv[3]
pp_adapter = sys.argv[4]
switch_ip = sys.argv[5]
switch = sys.argv[6]
node_type = sys.argv[7]
hmc_name = sys.argv[8]

filename = sys.argv[1] + "_" + sys.argv[2] + ".p.config"

args_str= "/home/raymond/config_gen.pl {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(sut, pp, sut_adapter, pp_adapter, switch_ip, switch, node_type, hmc_name)
args_str2 = "/framework/scripts/ts//ts /home/NDD/fvndd_dedicated.p -t standard_frames_dedicated -c 1 -g /Jenkins/config/{}".format(filename)

def test_run():

        args2 = shlex.split(args_str2)
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(args2,bufsize=-1,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


def main():

        args = shlex.split(args_str)
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(args,bufsize=-1,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        test_run()

if __name__== "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the output contained in `pipe` (`process` would be a better name)? Attributes like `returncode`, `stdout`, `stderr` may be useful to look at.

Comment: Since you've set `stdin` to a pipe, you may actually need to supply input to your processes. If you're not doing that, they are likely to be stuck in a waiting state, and will not end nor continue.

Comment: I'm betting that your applications/scripts return an error, which you won't see. I'd recommend doing `Popen(stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` and do a `while pipe.poll() is None: print(pipe.stdout.read())` to verify that the commands behave as expected. Do this one by one for your command executions to figure out why they're not working.

Comment: Thank you guys for help. I used stderr and now i am able to correct it